# Word for "able to be clearly pinpointed by its address or location"

Tags: vocabulary

This is a simple question for a word that I can use to describe something being unambiguously indicatable by (sort of) its address or location.

For example, let's assume we are detectives and we finally obtained a detailed address of a culprit that we want to find. Then we can say like,

> Finally, the culprit is totally **[???]able**.

The **[???]able** here is the word that I'm searching for now. I considered the words *locatable*, *localizable*, and *addressable*, but I'm not sure whether they are commonly used.

Comment: Knowing somebody's address doesn't mean that they are going to be there. I don't think the culprit is **totally** anything in this situation. All that you know is where to look next.

Answer (score 2):

You could use “traceable,” but “able to be located” may still be clearer; I don’t think the three words you offered are commonly used here at all.